# Python - How to start a non-interactive login shell with subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to use python subprocess to run a command, which i usually run in a login shell.

From the cmd script i would like to replicate in python, the following command is causing me troubles:

```
\usr\bin\bash.exe --login -i
```

The following commands open an interactive shell:

```
subprocess.run("\usr\bin\bash.exe --login -i")
subprocess.Popen("\usr\bin\bash.exe --login -i")
```

So to come back to my question: How can i make this non-interactive and pass a command to it?

Comment: Well, `-i` tells `bash` to start an interactive shell, though it's not necessary because any shell whose standard input is a terminal is also an interactive shell. You don't say how you want to feed the commands to the shell, but you'll probably want to use the `stdin` argument to create a pipe, if not simply specify the name of a script to execute when you start `bash` or use the `-c` option to specify its command.

Answer (score 1):

By trial and error I found out that specifying `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` is doing the job. If I want to run the command "ls" for example:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("\usr\bin\bash.exe --login -i", stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate("ls")
```

*NOTE:* After running `p.communicate()` it seems like it instantly logs out from the shell.

Comment: The purpose of `communicate` includes shutting down the process. Like the documentation says, you want to prefer `run` over `Popen` when you can; however, if you really want an interactive process you can engage in an input/output dialogue, you really do need `Popen`. The [`subprocess` tag info page](/tags/subprocess/info) has a few links to questions about this.

Comment: ... But then why do you say in your question that you want a "noninteractive" shell?